# How to format a string like #.#.#.#

Tags: java, random, string.format

I am new to Java so sorry if this is an easy problem. I am trying to generate a random IP address. I am generating the 4 numbers individually and want to format them like #.#.#.#

My code is as follows:

```
static final Random _random = new Random(Integer.parseInt(seed) / 2);

String ip = String.format(
    Locale.US,
    "#.#.#.#",
    _random.nextInt((254 - 1) + 1) + 1,
    _random.nextInt((254) + 1),
    _random.nextInt((254) + 1),
    _random.nextInt((254 - 1) + 1) + 1
);
```

I am getting the error

> too many arguments for format string (found:4, expected:0)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) should help you.

Comment: Consider using an array of char to build the string and then use that array to initialize your String object if you have trouble understanding how the String.format works.

Comment: What @Gendarme is saying, is that if you *read the documentation*, you'd find the answer, which is that formatting instructions start with a `%` sign, and that `d` is for decimal integer, so use `%d`.

Comment: Sorry I did read those links i just found it confusing. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Be aware that some of those random ip addresses will either be real, reserved, or not valid, if it matters

Comment: Thanks it doesn't really matter as it is for a game and I am already doing other checks to see if they are reserved or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need a range and assign it to your string (without much fuzz):

```
final Random random = new Random();
final String ip = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", random.nextInt(255) + 1,
    random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(255) + 1);
//System.out.printf("%s%n", ip);
```

Comment: I noticed you removed the ranges on the random values. Should I do that too? I was trying to generate only valid ips? The first and last numbers should never be 0.

Comment: If so, you need to add `1` to those (1st and last); `nextInt(int bound)` will returns a "pseudorandom" `int` value between `0` (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method mentioned above, or for the # formatting you can use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
Random random = new Random();
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###");
String value = new StringBuilder()
        .append(format.format(random.nextInt(256))).append(".")
        .append(format.format(random.nextInt(256))).append(".")
        .append(format.format(random.nextInt(256))).append(".")
        .append(format.format(random.nextInt(256))).toString();
```